# python: calling set over Itertools product object second time clear data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

when calling set(c) second time it show empty set, it clear data butit working fine for first time and address of object is also same .

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> b = [True, False]
>>> c = itertools.product(a, b)
>>> c
<itertools.product object at 0x7f7bbca23050>
>>> set(c)
set([('bbb', True), ('ccc', True), ('ccc', False), ('aaa', True), ('bbb', False), ('aaa', False)])
>>> set(c)
set([])
>>> c
<itertools.product object at 0x7f7bbca23050>
```

Answer (score 0):

you exhaust the generator `c` the first time you call `set`.

other example:

```
import itertools
a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
b = [True, False]
c = itertools.product(a, b)

for item in c:
    print(item) 
for item in c:
    print(item)
```

the second loop will not print anything.

if you need to be able to iterate twice over the same iterator, you can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20tee#itertools.tee):

```
from itertools import tee

c1, c2 = tee(c)
```

now you have 2 independent iterators.